# jQuery: Basics - Variable Scope Issue

Tags: jquery, variables, scope

I've hunted around for about an hour or so trying to glean whatever I could about variable scope in jscript/jquery and by all accounts, my code *should* work.  Right now I just want to be able to read a global variable from a function.  My code isn't working and right now it's very basic.  Eventually I will need to manipulate the global variable, but one step at a time here:

```
var fooBar;
fooBar = "blah";

$('.var').click(function (fooBar) {
    alert(fooBar);
});
```

HTML:

`<span class="var">(Button Test)</span>`

It returns [Object object] in the alert box.  I was really hoping it would return Blah for me.  I know this is a very very basic question, but all examples I'm finding are pretty complex and it's pretty difficult for me to boil it down to the very basic part that I need.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove it as a parameter, like this:

```
var fooBar;
fooBar = "blah";

$('.var').click(function () {
    alert(fooBar);
});
```

The reason you see `[Object object]` is that the first parameter passed to the function (and any other event handler in jQuery) is [the jQuery `event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), and that parameter being named the same means that inside your function `fooBar` refers to it, because it's more local.  Your variable is available inside, it's just getting overridden by a more local version currently because of the same name being used...remove it like I have above and you'll be all set.

Comment: I thought I had tried this earlier, but it might have been when I had more code in which could have caused my errors.  I still don't quite understand your explanation.  Are you saying the .click event was being passed as testVar and thus the `[Object object]`?

Comment: @mosquito - the first parameter, whatever you name it (usually `e` or `event`) will be the `click` event object jquery creates, and when you present it as a string, which `alert()` does, you'll get `[Object object]`.  It really has nothing to do with your previous `fooBar` variable, it just shared a name, so `alert()` was using an entirely different variable with the same name because it was "closer", or more local.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the fooBar from the function as it is making a local scope variable which will be being used rather than your global.

```
$('.var').click(function () {
    alert(fooBar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Global variables in Javascript are actually members of `window`, if you have a scoping conflict with a local variable, like your `fooBar` parameter, then you can fully qualify your global `fooBar` variable like so:

```
var fooBar;
fooBar = "blah";

$('.var').click(function (fooBar) {
    alert(window.fooBar);
});
```

In fact, I make it a point to always fully qualify global variables with `window` so as to avoid any confusion or conflicts. Indeed, I would write the whole thing like this:

```
window.fooBar = "blah";

$('.var').click(function (fooBar) {
    alert(window.fooBar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `fooBar` in the parameters for your function. This will suffice:

```
var fooBar;
fooBar = "blah";

$('.var').click(function() {
    alert(fooBar);
});
```

You've got too much code, is all :)